# Using Peewee ORM with MySQL date math

Tags: mysql, time, peewee

I'm trying to convert an application that uses MySQLdb to use Peewee instead. Most of the SELECTs and INSERTs are no problem, but one class of query has me puzzled.

The original code contains:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM {tbl} WHERE tail='{tail}' AND flight="+\
    "'{flight}' AND dest='{dest}' AND orig='{orig}' AND "+\
    "oooi='{oooi}' AND report_time > ('{time}' - INTERVAL 2 HOUR) "+\
    "AND report_time < ('{time}' + INTERVAL 2 HOUR)"
cmd = sql.format(tbl = self.table, tail=tail, flight=flight, dest=dest,
     orig=orig, time = report_time, oooi=oooi)

c.execute(cmd)
return c.fetchone()
```

Trying to rewrite that to use Peewee I've come up with:

```
oooi_rec = Oooi_rec.select().where(Oooi_rec.tail == self.tail, 
    Oooi_rec.flight == self.flight, 
    Oooi_rec.dest == self.dest, Oooi_rec.orig == self.orig, 
    Oooi_rec.oooi=self.oooi,
    Oooi_rec.report_time.between(low, high))
```

The bit that replaces "low" and "high" is what has me mystified for now. I'm trying to puzzle out how to use Peewee's fn() but it's slow going.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
low - SQL('interval 2 hour')
```

Also, so much sql injection in the way you had previously...yeesh.